# cd won't work when beginning by a "/"

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've got this problem for a long time and it's becoming a hard one. On Mac os x, when i type a directory such as `cd /adirectory/another/andelse`, I don't find it.  I only can type a direct one such as `cd Documents/Sites`. Well, my terminal don't recognize the directory absolute beginning by a "/". My terminal is bash.
I'm aware to all your answer.

Here is my `bash_profile` :

```
# Path for mysql
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

# Path for composer
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-01-25_at_17:56:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: I'm sure you probably did this but did you echo out the path to ensure everything is set to what you expected?  echo $PATH

Comment: What is the response to such a failing `cd` command? Are you sure you type a path that does indeed exist? When an absolute path is given to `cd`, `$PATH` is irrelevant.

Comment: it is not a new problem and cd doesn't work for every cd followed by a /

Comment: the terminal tell me -bash: cd: /htdocs/Monsite/dist: No such file or directory

Comment: You have not answered this: "Are you sure you type a path that does indeed exist?" I really doubt there'd be a `htdocs` in the root directory. What does `ls /` say? I suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the very basics of the directory structure.

Comment: Can you `cd` into a known existing directory, like `cd /usr/bin`?  If not, there might be something corrupt in your root directory.  Try running Disk Admin.

Answer (score 1):

When a directory starts with `/` it is a **fully qualified path or filename**.  Relative paths are based on your current directory, but fully qualified paths restart at the root directory (`/`) every time.  So `cd adir` works since `adir` is in your current directory, but `cd /adir` would fail since `adir` is not off of the root directory.

```
$ mkdir adir
$ ls
adir
$ cd adir
$ pwd
/home/chicks/Documents/se-code-review/x/adir
$ cd .. # not required, but starting from the same place as the other cd
$ cd /adir
-bash: cd: /adir: No such file or directory
$ ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  www
```

The `PATH` entries in your `.bash_profile` are different.  Those specify where to look for commands that are run, but that has no effect on how bash interprets directory names you specify.